# I am using ngRoute in my AngularJS project . Can I have specific action associated with each routes

Tags: angularjs

This is how I am doing .Here is my code.
I need to have specific function for each route

```
 var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute']);   
    App .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider            
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            });
    });
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Use `controller`.

Comment: I want to execute the something only when I go on that template.if I write it in controller will executed anyhow

Comment: No, controller is instantiated only when you navigate to the route.

Comment: I have only one controller

Comment: I see, this is wrong. You should better have separate controllers per route. I can't image any case when you would need to have the same controller for every route.

Comment: I am new to angularJS. And my project is almost complete separating controller will need lot of change is there any work around now.

Comment: What can I say, it's up to you. I'm just giving you good advice. Most likely your app will have problems (already has). You can fix it or allow to become even worse.

Comment: That single controller is probably a complete mess. Refactoring to multiple controllers/services shouldn't take long and would be well worth your effort

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use the 'resolve' function. Try like below

```
$routeProvider
 .when('/', {
  templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
  controller  : 'mainController',
  resolve: {
       val: function() {
         // do whats needed here
       return true;
  }
 })
 .when('/about', {
   templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
   controller  : 'mainController',
   resolve: {
       val: function() {
         // do whats needed here
       return true;
   }
  })
```